# Postgres Server Starting and Stopping on my Mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have installed a fresh copy of the Postgres server 9.4 on my Mac. I would now like to manually start and stop it from the command line. I have the following defined in my .bash_profile (of course the PATH is added as well)

```
export PGSQL_HOME=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin
```

I get the following when I tried to start the server

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data -l logfile start
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ /bin/sh: logfile: Permission denied
```

When I tried to see if there is any server running:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

Here is some more information:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ ps x | grep postgres
  263   ??  Ss     0:27.28 postgres: logger process    
  265   ??  Ss     2:04.57 postgres: writer process    
  266   ??  Ss     1:35.49 postgres: wal writer process    
  267   ??  Ss     0:21.52 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
  268   ??  Ss     0:20.12 postgres: stats collector process    
29416   ??  Ss     0:00.00 postgres: logger process    
29418   ??  Ss     0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer process    
29419   ??  Ss     0:00.09 postgres: writer process    
29420   ??  Ss     0:00.03 postgres: wal writer process    
29421   ??  Ss     0:00.03 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
29422   ??  Ss     0:00.08 postgres: stats collector process    
31113 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep postgres
```

This is boggling me. How could I make sure that I can start and stop a Postgres server manually from the command prompt on my Mac?

Comment: You installed 3rd-party code into `/Library`?  That is asking for trouble.  I would recommend using Macports of Homebrew to install 3rd-party tools.

Comment: I just downloaded the Postgres dmg file and just followed the default instructions. I guess I could get rid of it and do a fresh install in my preferred directory of choice.

Comment: I got rid of Postgres completely. I'm now trying a fresh install. Let me see if I could get it installed in a directory of my choice!

Comment: You should run `lsof -i:5432` in order to find the pid of the process. Personally I use [this](http://postgresapp.com/) and [this](https://eggerapps.at/postico/) and both are great.

Comment: For testing purposes, I recommend using: [PostgreSQL App](http://postgresapp.com). The service will be running while the app is opened.